# Contact form not clearing after submit and going to junk

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a contact form that is not clearing after submit and going to junk folder. The emails hit the junk folder from  xxx@secureserver.net

my html form looks like this:

```
<!-- Contact Form -->
   <form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" class="" action="includes/sendmail-without-phpmailer.php" method="post">


      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-outer">

                  <input id="form_name" name="form_name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required="">
                  <span class="icon fa fa-user"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>



         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-outer">
                  <input id="form_phone" name="form_phone" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
                  <span class="icon fa fa-phone"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-outer">
                  <input id="form_email" name="form_email" class="form-control required email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                  <span class="icon fa fa-envelope"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-outer">

                  <input id="form_subject" name="form_subject" class="form-control required" type="text" placeholder="Subject">
                  <span class="icon fa fa-question-circle"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-outer">

            <textarea id="form_message" name="form_message" class="form-control required" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <span class="icon fa fa-paper-plane"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <input id="form_botcheck" name="form_botcheck" class="form-control" type="hidden" value="" />
         <button type="submit" class="theme-btn btn-style-one" data-loading-text="Please wait..."><span class="btn-title">Submit Now</span></button>
         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-flat btn-theme-colored">Reset</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
<!--End Contact Form -->
```

validation looks like this:

```
<!-- form submit -->
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($) {
        $("#contact_form").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var form_btn = $(form).find('button[type="submit"]');
                var form_result_div = '#form-result';
                $(form_result_div).remove();
                form_btn.before('<div id="form-result" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;"></div>');
                var form_btn_old_msg = form_btn.html();
                form_btn.html(form_btn.prop('disabled', true).data("loading-text"));
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    dataType:  'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if( data.status == 'true' ) {
                            $(form).find('.form-control').val('');
                        }
                        form_btn.prop('disabled', false).html(form_btn_old_msg);
                        $(form_result_div).html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                        setTimeout(function(){ $(form_result_div).fadeOut('slow') }, 800);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

php mailer looks like this:

```
?php

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
  // Multiple recipients
  $to = 'someemail.com';


  $name = $_POST['form_name'];
  $email = $_POST['form_email'];
  $subject = $_POST['form_subject'];
  $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
  $message = $_POST['form_message'];

  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';


  $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
  $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
  $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
  $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';
  $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message | Contact Form';

  $from =  $email ;

  // Message
  $message = "$name $email $phone $message $referrer";

  // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
  $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
  $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
  $headers[] = "From: $from";

  // Mail it
  mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
?>
```

i got the email to submit while testing to my personal email but it hits junk folder and comes from secureserver.net and the from submit just says "please wait..."

Comment: The reasons for an email arriving to your junk folder can be due to : sender server having no PTR record, no DMARC, no DKIM, improper SPF , or sender email server is already black-listed for MX , etc.

Comment: `not clearing after submit` and `going to junk folder` are two entirely separate and unrelated problems, with entirely different possible solutions. [edit] your question to focus on one problem at at time. If you want to ask about two problems, then post two different questions, with a different focus (and a different, relevant [mre]) in each one. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the email problem though, the quickest and best thing we can usually do is simply to ask that you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail and work through all the possibilities on that list, until either you've fixed them all (in relation to your code and your email server) or at least you do enough of them that it starts working.

Comment: I can already see that you've broken the "Don't use a faux From: sender" rule that is mentioned there - making your mailserver impersonate an email account from a different mailserver is a _really_ great way to make the mail you send out look fake - because that's exactly what it is...your server is effectively pretending to be someone else's email account. How would you like it if I entered your email address into some website's form and then that website started sending emails which it claimed were from you? Clearly that should not be ok - and most mailservers will mark such messages as junk